# OleDB INSERT command error

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I have a database (i use MS ACCESS) I have this insert code, I can read data but got error when writing, I follow instruction but it didn't work 
here is my code

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@" provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; data source=\\sisc-erelim\4_Printing\VTDB\DB\VirginiTEADB2.accdb; Persist Security Info=False");

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, Password)" + "VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
```

And I always got this error,

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at VirginiTEAcorp.Form3.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\12-014s\My Documents\applications\Database\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form3.cs:line 34
```

Comment: When you debug, what the is the value of `cmd.CommandText` before you call `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You defined `@Username` and `@Password` parameters but you never used in your sql command.

How about?

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, [Password]) VALUES (@Username, @Password)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also you should use `Password` in square brackets on your sql command like `[Password]` because it is a [*`reserved keyword`*](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in MS Access.

If you don't this can cause an error like;

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword "Password"

Comment: @AlfredSanz Good to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this way

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, Password) VALUES (@Username,@Password)";
```

Answer (score 0):

A space is required in your insert statement:

```
ssword)" + "VALUES ('"
```

for example in your statement you have concatenated without allowing for a space.

Should be:

```
ssword)" + " VALUES ('"
```

For example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this :

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Accountstbl (Username, [Password]) VALUES (@Username,@Password)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
```

I hope this will work.

Cheer-up.