# Must declare the scalar variable "@photo"?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to save an image in an SQL database in the image format. I get this error `Must declare the scalar variable @photo` when I call `ExecuteNonQuery cmd`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace library
{
    public partial class moviepagemain : Form
    {
        public moviepagemain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            byte[] photo_aray;
        }

        private void picmovie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an image";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            textpic.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            picmovie.Image = Image.FromFile(textpic.Text);
        }

        private void buttonsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=sa;Password =12345678; Initial Catalog=library; server=raj; TRUSTED_CONNECTION=true;");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into movie ([title],[genere],[size],[resolution],[frame],[language],[subtitle],[runtime],[imdb],[synopsis],[cast],[director],[date],[picturebox]) values ('" + texttitle.Text + "', '" + textgenere.Text + "','" + textsize.Text + "','" + textres.Text + "','" + textframe.Text + "','" + textlang.Text + "','" + textsub.Text + "','" + texttime.Text + "','" + textimdb.Text + "','" + textsynop.Text + "','" + textcast.Text + "','" + textdirector.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").Trim() + "',@photo)", con);
            conv_photo();
            con.Open();
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here the exception error accrued // Must declare the scalar variable "@photo" 
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }

        void conv_photo()
        {
            if (picmovie.Image != null)
            {
                MemoryStream mst = new MemoryStream();
                picmovie.Image.Save(mst, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] photo_aray = new byte[mst.Length];
                mst.Position = 0;
                mst.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo_aray);
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you retrieving `@photo` from? shouldn't it be declared 1st?

Comment: If you are using @photo in Insert statement then you must first declare then set and then use it. Check this link and hope it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828935/oledb-insert-command-error

Comment: your `OleDbCommand` in your `conv_photo()` function is not the same one you call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused because:

1. You are not using the correct placeholder for parameter inside the command text
2. You are adding `@photo` parameter to an irrelevant `OleDbCommand` object

You have to replace `@photo` with `?` in the command text, i.e. replace `+ "',@photo)"` with `+ "',?)"`. This is how you specify parameter placeholders with `OleDbCommand`.

You should also pass `cmd` object as parameter to `conv_photo()`:

```
void conv_photo(OleDbCommand cmd)
{
   if (picmovie.Image != null)
   {
      MemoryStream mst = new MemoryStream();
      picmovie.Image.Save(mst, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      byte[] photo_aray = new byte[mst.Length];
      mst.Position = 0;
      mst.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo_aray);
   }    
}
```

then invoke `conv_photo` from within `buttonsave_Click` like this:

```
private void buttonsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ...

      conv_photo(cmd);
      con.Open();
      int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // cmd is now properly setup
      MessageBox.Show("done");
}
```

Comment: Giorgos Betsos i do as u told but still getting the same error "Must declare the scalar variable "@photo"."

Answer (score -4):

```
create procedure SP_Name(@Photo nvarchar(50))
{
as
begin
insert into table name(@Photo)
End
}
```

Comment: OP is not calling for any Stored Proc here! It's an inline query!